# What is: $A= \{ a \in \mathbb{N_0} ^ \mathbb{N} : \forall n\in \mathbb{N}, \sum_{i\in \{ 1,2,3,...,n\}}^{} a_i=n \} $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-theory

$\mathbb{N_0}$ is $ \mathbb{N}\cup {\{ 0\} }$. 
I can't really understand what this set stands for, and I need to know if its cardinality is finite or infinite, it would be really appreciated if someone can explain how to read these type of sets. 
Theres also this set, but I think I can understand it if I understand the first one.

$B= \{ a \in \mathbb{N_0} ^ \mathbb{N} : \forall n\in \mathbb{N}, \sum_{i\in \{ 1,2,3,4\}}^{}  a_i<10*\sqrt2 \} $

Comment: Where does this come from?

Comment: The definition of $A$ doesn't make sense. How can $\sum_{i \in \{1,2,3,4\}}a_i$ equal $n$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$? And in the definition of $B$, there's no mention of $n$ after $\forall n$, so that doesn't seem right either.

Comment: I'm really sorry i messed up on that it was meant to be until $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb N_0^{\mathbb N}$ is the set of all functions that map $\mathbb N$ into $\mathbb N_0$. In other words, this is the set of all *sequences* $(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ such that $a_i\in\mathbb N_0$ for all $i\in\mathbb N$.

(*Generally, for two sets $X$ and $Y$, the set $X^Y$ is the set of all functions mapping $Y$ into $X$.*)

This means that the set $A$ is the set of all of those sequences where $a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n=n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. This implies $a_1=1, a_2=1,\ldots$, and in general $a_n=(a_1+\ldots+a_n)-(a_1+\ldots+a_{n-1})=n-(n-1)=1$ i.e. $a_i=1$ for all $i\in\mathbb N$, so the set $A$ is a $1$-element set $\{(1,1,1,\ldots)\}$.

The definition of $B$ is a bit strange as $n$ does not play any role in the criterion $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4\lt 10\sqrt{2}$ - so that criterion *is* true for every $n$ if it is true at all. If there is no typo in the definition of $B$, then $B$ is simply:

$$B=\{a\in\mathbb N_0^{\mathbb N}:\sum_{i\in\{1,2,3,4\}}a_i\lt 10\sqrt{2}\}$$

i.e. set of all of those sequences where $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4\lt 10\sqrt{2}$ - which means this is an infinite set, as $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ can be chosen *somehow* to satisfy the above criterion (e.g. to be all zeros), and then $a_5,a_6,\ldots$ can be chosen arbitrarily.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, and I'm really sorry for messing up with the typo. I still didn't fully understand why the set $A$ is only one element set, I understood that all the $a_i = 1$, but couldn't the set have for example $\{ (1,1,1,1),(1,1,1,1,1,1,1),... \} $ more elements than one?

Comment: @Pwaol Look at the top of my answer. The elements of the set are sequences indexed by *the whole set* $\mathbb N$, with values from $\mathbb N_0$, i.e. they are all infinite sequences to start with.

Comment: Thank you, I think I get it now, to make sure, if the set $B$ was also for $i=1,2,3,...,n$ , it would still be an infinite set, since we can still choose $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 < 10\sqrt 2$ and the rest zeros?

Comment: @Pwaol I am not sure what you mean. The set $B$ is what it is. Do you want to modify the sum to be $\sum_{i\in\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}}a_i\lt 10\sqrt{2}$? If yes, the answer is "it will still be infinite" but not for the reasons you are mentioning. (Note the number of ways to make up a sum smaller than $10\sqrt{2}$ out of *natural* numbers (or zero) $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ is *finite*.) But - why stop at $a_4$?

Comment: It's just that I learnt this very recently and can't seem to understand the questions and how to answer them very well. especially this one got me stunned. didn't know how to tie between these sets and the infinite cardinalities, that we used functions to somehow "count them". I will just try to keep at it until I start to get how to do these stuff.  thanks for your help though I appreciate it

Comment: @Pwaol For now you seem to just need to distinguish finite sets from infinite sets. My thought for $B$: what about the sequences $(0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,0,\ldots)$ - i.e. those that have only one $1$ at $n$th place (and all the other elements are $0$). Those are all different and all belong to $B$.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it a little more, do you have any advice for me to improve myself in this subject?

Comment: Perhaps just two bits of advice: (1) Look at a lot of different examples. (The more the better), and (2) Keep your common sense in face of all the notation. ($\mathbb N_0^{\mathbb N}$ looks very puzzling, but when you realise this is just made up of sequences that you've seen many times before, it all looks much more down to Earth.)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate all the help